# how to remove first line of the xml and add two new lines with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I need a help regarding xml parsing, which means I have to delete the first line of the xml then add 2 extra lines. I know how to add two extra lines but don't know how to delete.

my xml source file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ENVELOPE>
   <SHIPMENTS>
      <HEA>
         <ADDRESSES>
            <AEM>
               <COMPANY_ID />
               <KDNR />
               <NAME>abcd pvt ltd</NAME>
               <NAME2 />
               <ABT />
               <STR />
            </AEM>
         </ADDRESSES>
      </HEA>
   </SHIPMENTS>
</ENVELOPE>
```

VBA Program

```
Dim Msg$
Dim NumFich As Integer
Dim CheminNomFichier As String
Private Sub Form_Load()
    NumFich = FreeFile
    CheminNomFichier = "C:\Users\nypaul\Desktop\out\output.xml"
    Open CheminNomFichier For Input As #NumFich
    Msg$ = Input(FileLen(CheminNomFichier), NumFich)
    Close #NumFich
    If Msg$ = "" Then
        MsgBox "le fichier est vide", vbCritical
    Else
        NumFich = FreeFile
        Open CheminNomFichier For Output As #NumFich
        Print #NumFich, "<?xml version="; 1#; " encoding="; ISO - 8859 - 1;> <!DOCTYPE StatusNotification SYSTEM ""; 3; StatusNotification.dtd; ""> " & Msg$
        Close #NumFich
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a proper [XML parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) rather than treating it as a text file.

Comment: The concept of a "line" is meaningless in XML. Newlines and spaces are semantically equivalent in many contexts.

Comment: What is the expected output please? Are you intending on removing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ?